# Trouble with pip

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am getting below error while installing `pip` module:

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install virtualenv venv1'

Comment: What was the command? Can you [edit] and copy/paste full text from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

try upgrading pip by `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Did update it, and it was a success  but then get the same, when trying install virtualenv -- 
 Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install virtualenv venv1'